# issue with editing crontab in AWS ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have created a cronjob in my local system using crontab -e

`crontab -e`

Its opening Nano editor in local Ubuntu system.
Then I added my cronjob. Thats fine.

But facing issue in AWS instance .
I tried same with my Ubuntu EC2 instance .

I connected AWS instance using SSH.
Ran `crontab -e`

Its giving

```
ubuntu@ip-1562-361-466-45563:~$ crontab -e
945
```

What is this 945, if i apply sudo its giving 888

why its not opening any editor like Nano or Vi.?

Comment: add the output of these commands to your question. `echo $VISUAL; echo $EDITOR; ls -l /usr/bin/editor /etc/alternatives/editor`

Answer (score 0):

`export EDITOR = nano` fixed my problem, now its opening with nano